# My Jquery click function is targeting all elements with the same class name

Tags: jquery, html

My Jquery click function is targeting all elements with the same class name, is there a way of only targeting to clicked element without changing class names?

It is basically an accordion whereby I want the description text to disappear when the section is clicked on and the PDF appears. However when I click on one section, all description text disappears.

```js
  if( $(".toggle .toggle-title").hasClass('active') ){
      $(".toggle .toggle-title.active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').show();
     }


     $(".toggle .toggle-title").click(function(){


          $('.text-content').toggle(function () {
          $(".text-content").css({display: "none"});
          }, function () {
          $(".text-function").css({display: "inline-block"});
          });



      if( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
       $(this).removeClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideUp(500);

      }
      else{
          $(this).addClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideDown(500);
      }

     });
```

```css
body {
  color: #4B4B4B;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
body a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #4B4B4B;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body section {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
body section h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

object{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

img{
height: 100px;
width: auto;
display: block;
}






/* Styles for Accordion */
#accordion-section{
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.image-holder{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  top: -5px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.toggle{
  background: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle .toggle-title {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle .toggle-title h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.title{
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}



.toggle .toggle-inner {
  padding: 7px 25px 10px 25px;
  display: none;
  margin: -7px 0 6px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.toggle .toggle-inner div {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.toggle .toggle-title{
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px;
  background: #252525;
  color: white;
}

.title-desc{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 25px 10px;
}

.text-content{
  display: inline-block;
}

.read-more{
  padding: 0px 25px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion-section">
          <div class="toggle">
             <div class="toggle-title">
                <div class="image-holder">
                   <img src="http://prototypes.infopro-insight.com/internal-dev/bb8-repo/risk/images/journal/JONTF_pattern.svgz">
                </div>
                <h3>
                   <div class="title">
                      <p>JOURNAL OF NETWORK FINANCE THEORY</p>
                      <p style="font-size:16px;">Call for papers</p>
                   </div>
                </h3>
             </div>
             <div class="text-content">
                <div class="title-desc">
                   <h3>Title: Example call for paper</h3>
                   <p>
                     Example Lorem Ipsum
                   </p>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="toggle-inner">
                <object style="height:calc(100vh - 70px)" data="http://prototypes.infopro-insight.com/test/MW/call_for_papers.pdf"></object>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>


       <div id="accordion-section">
          <div class="toggle">
             <div class="toggle-title">
                <div class="image-holder">
                   <img src="http://prototypes.infopro-insight.com/internal-dev/bb8-repo/risk/images/journal/JONTF_pattern.svgz">
                </div>
                <h3>
                   <div class="title">
                      <p>JOURNAL OF NETWORK FINANCE THEORY</p>
                      <p style="font-size:16px;">Call for papers</p>
                   </div>
                </h3>
             </div>
             <div class="text-content">
                <div class="title-desc">
                   <h3>Title: Example call for paper</h3>
                   <p>
                     Example Lorem Ipsum
                   </p>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="toggle-inner">
                <object style="height:calc(100vh - 70px)" data="http://prototypes.infopro-insight.com/test/MW/call_for_papers.pdf"></object>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: a class is a generic dom attribute, used to unify stylings and functions. Use ids to target things individually - and use the id in the function. ..

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `id="accordion-section"` is a duplicate ID. Don’t expect anything to work with this.

Comment: I do not understand your issue. Could you explain? is it about your page's functionality? is it a general question? right now when I click on one of the elements they open individualy

Comment: Yes they open individually, that asepct works perfectly. It is to do with the disappearing description "Title: Example call for paper, Example Lorem Ipsum". When you click on one section, the description for both sections disappears. I would only like the one that was clicked on to disappear.

Comment: you need  to use `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your current html structure you have provided and only want the tab that you clicked on to disappear, you could update your .click() function to cache the $(this) element you are selecting and select the sibling element with a class of text-content to toggle your display.

```
if ($(".toggle .toggle-title").hasClass('active')) {
    $(".toggle .toggle-title.active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').show();
}
$(".toggle .toggle-title").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this); //create a $this variable to cache the element you are selecting into a variable to use multiple times throughout your .click function
    $this.siblings('.text-content').toggle(function() { //the element with a class of text-content is a sibling of the element with the class toggle-title, so you use siblings to select the text-content element
        $(".text-content").css({ display: "none" });
    }, function() {
        $(".text-function").css({ display: "inline-block" });
    });

    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.removeClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideUp(500);
    } else {
        $this.addClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideDown(500);
    }
});
```